# Initialize a flexible array of arrays in a struct

Tags: c

The title corresponds to my last attempt, I try to store color values ​​corresponding to walls, a bit like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t RGB[3];
typedef RGB ColorArray[];

typedef struct {
    int wall_num;
    ColorArray wall_colors;
} Map;

int main(void)
{
    int wall_num = 3;

    ColorArray wall_colors = {
        *(RGB){ 255, 0, 0 },
        *(RGB){ 0, 255, 0 },
        *(RGB){ 0, 0, 255 }
    };

    Map my_map = {wall_num, wall_colors}; // error: non-static initialization of a flexible array member

    return 0;
}
```

But I get this:

```
error: non-static initialization of a flexible array member
```

I tried other ways with pointers but I quickly realized that it was pointing to anything and so I got any colors until a segfault...

Is there a way to do it like this ? Or is it just the wrong way to go and I have to start all over again ?

**UPDATE - (SELF ANSWER)**:

So I decided to call malloc() because no alternative was satisfactory for my case, I share what I did if it can help someone:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef uint8_t RGB[3];
typedef RGB RGB_Array[];

typedef struct {
    int wall_num;
    RGB_Array wall_colors;
} Map;

void print_map (Map *m) {
    printf("wall_num: %d\n", m->wall_num);
    for (int i = 0; i < m->wall_num; ++i) {
        printf("wall_colors[%d]: (R:%d, G:%d, B:%d)\n", i,
               m->wall_colors[i][0],
               m->wall_colors[i][1],
               m->wall_colors[i][2]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int wall_num = 3;

    RGB_Array color_arr = {
        {255,0,0},
        {0,255,0},
        {0,0,255}
    };

    Map* map = malloc(sizeof(Map) + sizeof(color_arr));

    map->wall_num = wall_num;

    memcpy(map->wall_colors, color_arr, sizeof(color_arr));

    print_map(map);

    free(map); // free is for example

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, jxh's answer is still interesting and perfectly does what was asked for, even if it doesn't suit me personally, I validate it anyway.

Comment: You typically have to use `malloc()` etc. to allocate a structure with a FAM.

Comment: This way of initializing an array wouldn't work for a regular array either.

Comment: @Shawn I thought about it but I thought it was silly to have to allocate/deallocate something that is only used for that, I'm thinking how to get around the problem otherwise I'll resign myself to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an array name to initialize an array variable anyway.

There is no memory associated with the flexible array member. It is a convenience to allow you to have a name for the end of the `struct` to refer to the array that you intend to allocate behind the `struct`.

Typically, you would use `malloc()` and add the size of the array to the size of the `struct` to get a single object to represent your structure with the flexible array.

However, you can do it off the "stack" by defining a new structure where the flexible array member is replaced with an array of the appropriate size, and then casting a pointer to this structure to your desired type.

Alternatively, you could use a `union` and avoid the casting.

Both techniques are illustrated below. First some helpers:

```
...
#define MAP_TEMPLATE(N) struct { \
    int wall_num; \
    RGB wall_colors[N]; \
}
...
void print_map (Map *m) {
    printf("wall_num: %d\n", m->wall_num);
    for (int i = 0; i < m->wall_num; ++i) {
        printf("wall_colors[%d]: (R:%d, G:%d, B:%d)\n", i,
               m->wall_colors[i][0],
               m->wall_colors[i][1],
               m->wall_colors[i][2]);
    }
}
```

Then using a new structure:

```
    MAP_TEMPLATE(3) my_map1 = {
        wall_num,
        { { 155, 0, 0 },
          { 0, 155, 0 },
          { 0, 0, 155 },
        },
    };

    print_map((Map *)&my_map1);
```

And using a union:

```
    union {
        MAP_TEMPLATE(3) _;
        MAP_TEMPLATE();
    } my_map2 = {
        { wall_num,
          { { 255, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 255, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 255 },
          },
        },
    };

    print_map((Map *)&my_map2);
```